# gitlab dependent jobs using needs

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-api

I have a hopefully a simple query.
Say I have 3 jobs :

- job1
- job2
- job3

which runs first in all branches, next I have a job (hidden job say .job4).
This job4 is extended by all my further jobs in pipeline (say job5, job6, job7, job8.....)

Back to my question:
Job4 needs to be dependent on job1, job2, job3 (needs) only when I am running branch1,
but if I am running any branch other than branch1 in that case I only want to wait for job1 to complete but not job2 and job3 to completed

In other words

- If current branch is branch1 , job4 should be running only after job1, job2, job3 (dependent on 3 jobs)
- If current branch is not branch1 , just wait for job1 but not for job2, job3 to even complete

I was not able to use below logic , the problem I see is that gitlab do not recognize if rule with `needs`...what can I do better than this?

```
  .job4:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^branch1.*/'
      needs:
        - job: job1
          artifacts: true
        - job: job2
          artifacts: true
        - job: job3
          artifacts: true
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^branch1.*/'
      needs:
        - job: job1
          artifacts: true
      when: always
```

Job1 job2 and job3 are simple jobs
example

```
job1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - |
      echo "job1" > job1.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - job1.txt
  rules:
    - when: always



job2:
  stage: build
  script:
    - |
      echo "job2" > job2.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - job2.txt
  rules:
    - when: always


job3:
  stage: build
  script:
    - |
      echo "job3" > job3.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - job3.txt
  rules:
    - when: always
```

The error I get is `rule config contains unknown keys: needs`

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this or show the full configuration including all the relevant jobs and rules? Is the problem that you're also excluding `job2` and `job3` from the pipeline based on the same branch rule?

Comment: Not excluding jobs2 and job3, I am not excluding any job from pipeline...
if branch is branch 1 than job 4 is dependent on job 1, job2, job3 to completed before job 4 kicks off...
If branch is not branch branch 1 just depend on job1 to completed before job 4 to start (do not wait for job2 and job3 to wrap)

Job1, job2 and job3 are simple say I have simple script 
Job1 to echo "I am in job1"
Job2 to echo "I am in job2"
Job3 to echo "I am in job3"

Answer (score 1):

You can't change `needs:` based on `rules:`, so you'll need to define two jobs.

```yaml
.job4:
  script:
    - echo "job4"

job4_branch1:
  extends:
    - '.job4'
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^branch1.*/'
  needs: [job1, job2, job3]


job4_not_branch1:
  extends:
    - '.job4'
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^branch1.*/'
  needs: [job1]
```

Note that `artifacts: true` is the default, so it doesn't need to be included.

Another way to do this without introducing another job name is to use `include:rules:`

Create two files:

```yaml
# not-branch1.yml

.job4:
  # ...
  needs: [job1]
```

```yaml
# branch1.yml

.job4:
  needs: [job1, job2, job3]
```

Then in your main `.gitlab-ci.yml` include either file conditionally:

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml

include:
  - local: branch1.yml
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^branch1.*/'
  - local: not-branch1.yml
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^branch1.*/'

# ...

job5:
  extends:
    - '.job4'

# etc.
```